# How do I create dependency diagrams in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I've just started working with Sphinx and I need to generate a diagram showing the dependencies between different functions (some of which may be part of an object).

Sphinx can produce very nice [inheritance diagrams](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/inheritance.html), but I need to show the relationships between functions, not objects. I have produced something myself using Graphviz but it doesn't (yet) work with object methods and the outputs can't easily be imported into Sphinx documentation.

Example functions:

```py
def function1():
    return 1

def function2():
    return function1() * 2

def function3():
    return function1() + function2()
```

And an example with objects:

```py
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
      pass

    def function1(self):
        return 1

    def function2(self):
        return self.function1() * 2

    def function3(self):
        return self.function1() + self.function2()
```

I am looking to create a graph like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4FTA.png) for the examples above.

Ideally it would be generated using Sphinx and/or be able to be automatically generated and be able to be automatically placed in Sphinx documentation. Is there an easy way of doing this?